# Elementary question: Integral of area function

Tags: definite-integrals, area

I am sorry for this elementary question. I have searched a bit but haven't found what I am looking for precisely. I am trying to determine how to the volume of liquid in an irregularly shaped container changes with increasing height ($z$) in the container. I have a function that defines the cross sectional area of the container (in the $x$ $y$ plane). I thought I would be able to integrate (actually a numerical approximation, trapezoidal rule) the function at each $z$ and find the volume of the container below the current $z$ being integrated at. However, this is giving unexpected (too large) of values. Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks! AM.

Comment: This is a problem where having the actual formulas would be essential to helping you. What is the function that defines the "cross-sectional area?" What does your work look like when you used the trapezoid rule to approximate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating the area function is the right thing to do. For instance, if the area at height $h$ is $\pi h^2$, then the volume between height $0$ and $2$ is 
$$
\int_0^2 \pi h^2 ~dh = \left. \pi\frac{h^3}{3} \right|_0^2 = \pi \frac{8}{3}. 
$$
If you were to do this numerically, using steps of size $1/2$, you'd evaluate the area at heights $\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{4}, \frac{7}{4}$, and multiply each by $\frac{1}{2}$ (the "height" of each "slab"); you'd get

$$
\frac{1}{2} \pi \frac{1^2}{4^2} +\frac{1}{2} \pi \frac{3^2}{4^2} +\frac{1}{2} \pi \frac{5^2}{4^2} +\frac{1}{2} \pi \frac{7^2}{4^2} =\\
\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{16}(1 + 9 + 25 + 49) \\
= \frac{21 \pi}{8}
$$
which differs from the exact answer by only a few percent.

Comment: Thank you! the multiplying by "slab thickness" was what I was missing. accepted.